# Why isn't my form posting back my td information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I'm trying to post back the value that's inside the `<td>` but for some reason it's not posting it back, all the properties are either null or set to their default value such as 0.

It should post back the values when I click this button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-info"> <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> </button>
```

But for some reason it's not grabbing things like `<td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.ServerID)</td>` and posting it back

Here is the razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Dashboard"))
                    {
                        <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Server Name</th>
                                    <th>Credentials</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Modify</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.ServerID)</td>
                                    <td>Data</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Endpoint)</td>
                                    if (Model.IsRunning)
                                    {
                                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Running</span></td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Stopped</span></td>
                                    }
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> </button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-stop"></i> </button>

                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-info"> <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> </button>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }
```

And the Controller

```
 public ActionResult Edit(ServerModel serverModel)
        {
            var model = serverModel;
            return View();
        }
```

the model properties are null or 0 as I said.

And here is the Model

```
 public class ServerModel
    {
        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }
        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ServerID)

 @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.ServerID)`

DisplayTextFor will only render the item as text.

Including the hidden field will include them in the payload sent to the server - as form items.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint on `var model = serverModel;` it's null. And that's the issue, The properties are not being set when posting the form. It doesn't matter if it redirects or not, I'm fimply trying to retrieve the values first.

Comment: ah, i see now. See edit. DisplayTextFor will not render the property as a form field - it will just render the text.

Comment: Interesting! That seems like a "hacky" solution, what would be a more proper way of doing so? Is there any other razor syntax I can use to display a piece of text that will send as form data?

Comment: you're not editing the data, so it's valid... if it was a textbox - `TextBoxFor()` that would only render one field - an `<input type=text>` control which would be included in the payload on the post...